# Is there a way to affect some react components without affecting the other components or pages?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have an index.css that have some styles in it and it is imported here:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   
    <App />
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

I just want it to affect this part :

```
// global.tsx
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage from "../../pages/Authentication/Login";
import SignupPage from "../../pages/Authentication/Signup";
import '../../index.css'
const Global = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignupPage />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Global;
```

so as you can see i moved the import only to this part instead of being imported in the main.tsx . but still the css file affects the other pages and components

I hope someone helps me

Answer (score 0):

`CSS` exhibits an inherently global nature. To establish a more confined scope for your CSS, it is advisable to employ techniques such as CSS modules or utilise `CSS-in-JS` libraries, such as styled components.